# Lib not found: NICE-NOTFOUND when installing licode on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I'm trying to install Licode on a Ubuntu 12.04 vps (an Azrure vps actually).
I'm following [this guide](http://lynckia.com/licode/install.html).
I'm stuck in step 4 (install all Licode components).
When I run `/licode/scripts/installErizo.sh`, it says that:

```
CMAKE Error at erizo/CMakeLists.txt: 6 (message):
 lib not found: NICE-NOTFOUND check README
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 erizo/CMakeLists.txt:48 (test_lib)
```

I have googled for this issue but haven't found anything yet. Is "NICE" the name of a package that I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**
Reading code from the .sh file and trace to the CMakeLists.txt file. I found that there is a line of building code:

```
find_library(NICE nice HINTS "${THIRD_PARTY_LIB}")
```

Looks like NICE is exactly a third party library.
I found nothing on Google about a libaray named "NICE" but in the `/src/erizo` folder, i can see `NiceConnection.h` and `NiceConnection.cpp` file.

However i still don't know how to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'nice' utility that is used to adjust running program priorities. I wonder if this could be the missing program? Usually it is installed by default. A quick google for 'nice deb' does not turn up much of anything useful. If you found a deb of the nice utilities, I wonder if that would solve your issue? HTH!

Comment: I've tried installing on ubuntu 14 and it's ok. Seem like Nice is a package of Ubuntu 14.

Comment: I found NiceConnection.cpp here https://gist.github.com/jcague/4353342 -- There are a few other repos for it. Is this code necessary for your build? I don't know your code so am not sure.